# how to get bus and dev info using c

Tags: c, serial-port, usb

I want to read bus and dev of usb serial device attached to PC using C language. How can I get that, please help me...example I want to read Trust International usb device bus info and Device info from the below.

```
lsusb
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 15d9:0a4f Trust International B.V. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:c312 Logitech, Inc. DeLuxe 250 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How to get using C language?

Comment: I hope, this will help you .https://github.com/gregkh/lsusb

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in standard C, since standard C says nothing about USB.

You need to use platform-specific code, which makes it very suitable to wrap it up into a library.

One such library which is very commonly used is [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/). It's described like this:

> libusb is a C library that gives applications easy access to USB devices on many different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute the lsusb from a [popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)() method and then fgets() as character arrays the individual lines reported by lsusb.

from each array then extract the bus and Device id using sscanf() or any other String manipulation function of your choice since the position of the bus and device id is always fixed.